# Getting "No such file or directory" But it exists

Tags: centos, directory

I'm trying to cd into this directory

`/lib/modules/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64/build`

However, it is saying this directory doesn't exist when it clearly does. When I enter the command `ls -l /lib/modules/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64/build`  I get this.

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     51 Mar 11  2016 build -> ../../../usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64`

What does this mean and how can I get access to this directory.

Comment: It appears to be a soft link to a directory that doesn't exist.  What does `ls -lL /lib/modules/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64/build` show?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it gives this `ls: cannot access /lib/modules/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64/build: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is there a `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64` directory?  A soft link does not have to point to an existing file or directory.  That's known as a dangling or broken link.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/how-can-i-find-broken-symlinks

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah. It doesnt exist. I will check that url out.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so why are these directories showing two different kernel versions? Should I just delete this question and ask another one?

Comment: I have no way to tell.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hm alright well thank you for your help